# View code for ast when debugging Babel plugin

Tags: javascript, babeljs

Babel gives access to the AST nodes in the visitor. However, for debugging, I sometimes want to see the source code around the node I'm looking at currently.

What is the recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Currently I'm first saving a reference to the path, by running `p = path` in the console.

Then I go up the call stack to `babel.transform`, where I have access to the code through the local variables.

Then I run:

```
code.substr(p.node.start, 100)
```